# PHP: a class which reads all incoming HTTP request

Tags: php

I am trying to read in ever file the browser is requesting. Like all the CSS,JS etc.. Is this possible with PHP.

I did something like this with JSP, but how do i do it with PHP?

Comment: You could create a rewrite rule in whatever server you're using (Apache, nginx, etc.), to pass any HTTP requests through a specific PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use apache to redirect all requests to a php file, passing the actual file requested as a url parameter, record the request then serve the file.

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(js|css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ request.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

where `request.php` is the php file that is to record the request and `js|css` is a `|` separated list of extensions you want to redirect.

then to serve the file with php:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

or

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

followed by

```
echo file_get_contents($_GET['request']);
```

**Also, importantly, do not forget to validate the requested file.**

**Note** There may be additional helpful or required headers like content-length, cache-control and pragma. You will need to evaluate your exact needs and work with them accordingly.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($_GET['request']));
```

Comment: Both Tim and you have the right answer. Thank you ;) Will reward in 10min because i can't select the best answer within 10 minutes

Comment: I implemented your answer and it worked ;). But when i go to www.site.com/test.html. I only see test.html not all the files which are requested in test.html it self. Is the main i idea that i parse the file myself and then include the css/js/etc or am i doing something wrong?