# PHP HTTP Request capture

Tags: php

I would like to capture every incoming HTTP requests. Not only the HTTP Request which requests the page but also if the page has any images and/or css etc.. How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: In what way do you believe that this question is more constructive than [the identical one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700894/php-a-class-which-reads-all-incoming-http-request) that was closed for you yesterday?

Comment: It's XY problem all the way down. Instead of letting your web server do the logging and then parsing this log with PHP (or whatever, actually) when it's suitable, you're trying to make all the requests go through PHP first.

Comment: Because this question is not only about the incoming request wihch asks for the page but also for every request. Which i dont get is the reason it was closed since i got a valid response so the question was clear, atleast i thought. But if this isn't true or w/e i will delete this question...

Comment: Your question is going to be closed as duplicate of... your own question

Comment: You can look at `accesslog` found http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html, and then you can log for regular php files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite urls like :

```
http://yourserver.com/test.css
http://yourserver.com/test.img
http://yourserver.com/test.js
...
```

To something like

```
http://yourserver.com/content.php?file=test.css
http://yourserver.com/content.php?file=test.img
http://yourserver.com/content.php?file=test.js
```

This way you could use `content.php` to either:

- track the request and just echo the requested content
- and/or place php code inside those files that can be executed. (like colors in css,...)

Comment: If I'm mistaken please correct me, but won't caching fail?

Comment: What do you mean? And how is this related to the question?

Comment: Generally static files are placed without going through php because they should be cached. PHP files are never cached and thus the user will end up downloading .css, .img, and .js over and over causing unnecessary bandwidth usage.

Comment: ??? Have you ever heard about a caching HTTP proxy? And of course a cache can be implemented using PHP as well